# Convert from ASCII to Hex in Python

Tags: python, hex, ascii

I'm trying to convert a string with special characters from ASCII to Hex using python, but it doesn't seem that I'm getting the correct value, noting that it works just fine whenever I try to convert a string that has no special characters. So basically here is what I'm doing:

```
import binascii

s = "D`Cزف³›"
s_bytes = str.encode(s)
hex_value = str(binascii.hexlify(s_bytes),'ascii')
print (hex_value)
```

***Output***

> 446043d8b2d981c2b316e280ba

Where the output should be (using online converter https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html):

> 446043632641b3203a

Comment: Change your character encoding on that site to UTF-8 and you'll see it matches.  You can't expect sensible conversion if your input isn't actually ASCII.

Comment: Your input string is not ASCII

Comment: Note `s` is not an ASCII only string, so *ASCII* to Hex is a misnomer.  `encode` default uses `UTF-8`, so you are getting the bytes of a UTF-8-encoded byte string as hexadecimal values.

Comment: `hex_value = ''.join([f'{ord(c):x}' for c in s])` would get what you want, but is it what you need?   How would you convert it back since there are 2-, 3-, and 4-digit values for some characters.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I updated the question again. You're right my code might be wrong but I'm trying to get the converted value 446043632641b3203a from D`Cزف³›

Comment: @MarkTolonen What you suggested would do the work actually, but what do you mean by convert it back? What are these digit values you mentioned?

Comment: `hex(ord('D')) = 0x44`, `hex(ord('›')) = 0x203a`.  You get a varying number of digits for each character.

Comment: Seems like we are solving an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  Why do you want this?  What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks @MarkTolonen. Is there a way to have spacing in the converted value?

Comment: Put a space in the `' '.join` in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.encode(s)` defaults to `utf8` encoding, which doesn't give you the byte values needed to get the desired output.  The values you want are simply Unicode ordinals as hexadecimal values, so get the ordinal, convert to hex and join them all together:

```py
s = 'D`Cزف³›'
h = ''.join([f'{ord(c):x}' for c in s])
print(h)
```

```
446043632641b3203a
```

Just realize that Unicode ordinals can be 1-6 hexadecimal digits long, so there is no easy way to reverse the process since you have no spacing of the numbers.